# Editing a function in a Wordpress Plugin (or is there a way to create a 'Child plugin')?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, class, plugins

I am using a plugin called [Lightweight Social Icons](https://github.com/tomusborne/lightweight-social-icons), and I want to add my own custom icons without having to edit the parent plugin.

Here's a snippet of the parent plugin:

```
class lsi_Widget extends WP_Widget {
 ... (class functions are in here)
}

function lsi_icons( $options = '' ) {
    $options = array (
        'email' => array(
            'id' => 'email',
            'name' => __( 'Contact', 'lightweight-social-icons' )
        ),
        'delicious' => array(
            'id' => 'delicious',
            'name' => __( 'Delicious', 'lightweight-social-icons' )
        ),
        'deviantart' => array(
            'id' => 'deviantart',
            'name' => __( 'DeviantArt', 'lightweight-social-icons' )
        ),
        'digg' => array(
            'id' => 'digg',
            'name' => __( 'Digg', 'lightweight-social-icons' )
        ),
        'facebook' => array(
            'id' => 'facebook',
            'name' => __( 'Facebook', 'lightweight-social-icons' )
        ),
    );

    return apply_filters( 'lsi_icons_defaults', $options );
}
```

I want to edit the `lsi_icons()` function so that I can add my own icons, but it is outside of the `lsi_Widget` class. I have a child theme with a `functions.php` file, which I am using to make changes to other plugins using actions and hooks, however, I'm not sure how to do the same for this plugin since the function I want to modify is outside of the class. I've been looking for a way to create 'Child plugins' the same way you do Child Themes, but I can't seem to find a clear answer on how to do it. So is there some other way to do what I'm trying to do?

Link to the LSI Plugin Github page: https://github.com/tomusborne/lightweight-social-icons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's don't matter, where is filter located. You can access it from `functions.php` file of your theme/child theme.

Here is code:

```
function ww_change_lsi_icons($options){
  //here you can see all icons added. Add, delete, change them through $options variable

  return $options;
}
add_filter( 'lsi_icons_defaults', 'ww_change_lsi_icons' );
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you! This is exactly what I needed! I didn't know you can still use filters to access the function outside of the class! Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help you